# Why Does "apt-get install npm" Remove A Bunch Of Plesk Files?

Tags: apt

See:

```
root@iandpdev2:~# apt-get install npm 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
The following extra packages will be installed:   
gyp javascript-common
libc-ares-dev libjs-node-uuid libssl-dev libssl-doc   libssl1.0.0
libv8-3.14-dev libv8-3.14.5 node-abbrev node-ansi node-archy  
node-async node-block-stream node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar  
node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fstream  
node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-glob
node-graceful-fs   node-gyp node-inherits node-ini
node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile   node-lru-cache node-mime
node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream   node-node-uuid node-nopt
node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once   node-osenv node-qs
node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry   node-rimraf
node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar  
node-tunnel-agent node-which nodejs nodejs-dev zlib1g-dev 

Suggested packages:   
node-hawk node-aws-sign node-oauth-sign
node-http-signature 

The following packages will be REMOVED:  
libpam-plesk plesk-base plesk-config-troubleshooter plesk-core
plesk-l10n   plesk-mail-pc-driver plesk-management-node
plesk-roundcube   plesk-service-node-utilities plesk-web-hosting
pp-sitebuilder   psa-drweb-configurator psa-horde psa-imp psa-ingo
psa-kronolith   psa-libxml-proxy psa-mail-driver-common
psa-mailman-configurator psa-mnemo   psa-passwd psa-php5-configurator
psa-phpmyadmin psa-phppgadmin   psa-pylibplesk psa-turba psa-updates
wpb-core wpb-headers 

The following NEW packages will be installed:  
gyp javascript-common libc-ares-dev libjs-node-uuid libssl-dev
libssl-doc   libv8-3.14-dev libv8-3.14.5 node-abbrev node-ansi
node-archy node-async   node-block-stream node-combined-stream
node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream   node-forever-agent
node-form-data node-fstream node-fstream-ignore  
node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp
node-inherits   node-ini node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile
node-lru-cache node-mime   node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream
node-node-uuid node-nopt   node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog
node-once node-osenv node-qs   node-read node-read-package-json
node-request node-retry node-rimraf   node-semver node-sha
node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent   node-which nodejs
nodejs-dev npm zlib1g-dev 

The following packages will be upgraded:  
libssl1.0.0
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042515/plesk-jxcore-fails-installing-npm-modules

Answer (score 0):

Same thing.
But i do :

```
apt-get install npm
```

I answered question Y/n : n

After i do :

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade npm
```

After i do

```
apt-get install -s npm
```

And when i do :

```
apt-get install npm
```

I don't see deleted package and i install npm without delete Plesk :)